# Connecting from one Hawtio to another

Tags: apache-karaf, hawtio

I'm struggling to get Hawtio remote connections working.  I've two servers, both running Hawtio inside Karaf.  One server is running an app server for a website and the other is running Camel and ActiveMQ to provide integration and messaging.  I've an Apache reverse proxy in front of the messaging box, through which I can access Hawtio.  I want to use this as the route in for administration tools.

My understanding is that I should be able to connect through the middleware box's Hawtio onto the app server's Hawtio.  However, I can't get the connection screen to let me through.  I've tried numerous combinations of IP addresses, hostnames, paths and clicked the "proxy" box on and off but to no avail.  Sometimes a log-in screen appears but it appears if I put in nonsense as the hostname, so I think it is a red herring.

If I open up the firewall, I can access Hawtio directly on both boxes.

[image: screenshot from 2014-03-17 17 58 53]

What am I missing?

Thanks for any guidance.

J.

Comment: What version of Karaf and hawtio are you using?

Comment: Hi Claus - it's Karaf 2.3.3 and Hawtio 1.2.1

Comment: make sure you enable the Proxy flag; this is to avoid CORS issues as you can't open any old port in a normal web app

Comment: BTW if you try the hawtio Chrome Extension, you don't need to use Proxy's at all

Comment: Hi James.  I've tried with the Proxy flag on and off but no luck.  Just to be sure, am I right that jolokia is listening on the same port as Karaf and that the usual path is "hawtio/jolokia"?  Should it launch another browser window or load the remote Hawtio within the same window?  As above, I can get it to launch a new window, which then shows the log-in screen but it won't accept the credentials - in these cases the URL in the browser address bar shows:-

`https://my.domain.com/hawtio/index.html?url=%2Fhawtio%2Fproxy%2Fapplication-server-hostname%3A8181%2Fhawtio%2Fjolokia#/login`

Comment: I've also tried the Chrome extension but can't access the main Hawtio (NB going via port 443 due to reverse proxy).  It gives me:-

`Error: A network error occurred. at Object.send (chrome-extension://SNIP/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js?v=1.2.3:2:85935) at ...SNIP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked around this.  Instead of installing Hawtio in every container, I only installed Jolokia.  I then reverse-proxied this out of the web server layer and used the Chrome plug-in to connect to each container.